# events as JSON feed, but passing extra parameters?

Tags: fullcalendar

in the example code we're able to get events from a JSON feed by passing a URL.

> $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>       events: "/myfeed.php" });

fullCalendar will visit a link like this: /myfeed.php?start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646

Can I pass extra parameters to myfeed.php url? for example if I wanted to restrict events that are returned for a specific resource id.

ex: /myfeed.php?resourceid=1&start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this has worked for me in the past.  So your code should just be:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ events: "/myfeed.php?resourceid=1" });
```

Now I'm just having problems crossing domains!