# How can I pass back extra parameters in my events call when using jquery fullcalendar and asp.net-mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using jquery fullcalendar and asp.net-mvc.  It works fine out of the box [using this as an example](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/) and [this asp.net-mvc example](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/using-fullcalendar-jquery-component-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) but I wanted to see if there is a way to  pass extra parameters to the controller action.  It seems like this code in the asp.net-mvc example only passes 2 arguments to the Getevents controller action but i want to pass a few more parameters that i have stored in hidden inputs on the client side.

I see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240699/events-as-json-feed-but-passing-extra-parameters), which is similar, but I need to set these parameter dynamically

Is this possible using this jquery plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set any AJAX option using the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            myparam1: 'foo',
            myparam2: 'bar'
        }
    }
});
```

The `data` parameter could be used to send any additional parameter as if you were using a regular `$.ajax` call.

Comment: thanks . . i am trying to figure out how to change the data on a button click for example.  My point is the data elements are not set at the time i initialize the fullcalendar . .

Comment: In this case you could use [`events (as a function)`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/). This will allow you to pass some custom array object which you could manipulate on button clicks and stuff to dynamically add and remove elements to it.